Celery huge queue running
I have a large Celery task queue that includes multiple nested chains, groups, and chords. The primary structure is a chain. Constructing this entire queue at once is very slow and happens in a single thread. I created a chunk_queue generator that produces parts of the chain, allowing for incremental execution. However, I need each subsequent chunk to execute only after the previous chunk has completed. Has anyone dealt with such large queues before and can suggest a strategy for executing them efficiently?
I'm trying to use the celery-dyrygent package, but it constructs the entire task queue before starting the execution of the chain. Dynamically adding tasks to an existing queue is not allowed.

Could you provide us with a [example] so that we can understand the problem you are having?
